# What is the correct way to build a SOAP request for complexType sequence any using php:SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm struggling to understand how [SoapClient](http://php.net/soapclient) works.

**wdsl**

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="[redacted]">
      <s:element name="GetResult">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Foo" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Bar">
              <s:complexType mixed="true">
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:any />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      [..]
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  [..]
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The owner of the webservice suggests the request has to look like:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetResult xmlns="[redacted]">
            <Bar>
                <Bar>
                    <Qux>bar_qux_value</Qux>
                </Bar>
            </Bar>
            <Foo>foo_string</Operation>
        </GetResult>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What I think I should do is:

```
$client = new \SoapClient($url_to_wsdl);
$result = $client->GetResult([
    "Foo" => "foo_value",
    "Bar" => [
        "Bar" => [
            "Qux" => "bar_qux_value"
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But that gives me:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'any' property

So then perhaps I need to do this?

```
$client = new \SoapClient($url_to_wsdl);
$result = $client->GetResult([
    "Foo" => "foo_value",
    "Bar" => [
        "any" => [
            "Bar" => [
                "Qux" => "bar_qux_value"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But that builds the request like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetResult>
            <ns1:Foo>foo_value</ns1:Operation>
            <ns1:Bar>bar_qux_value</ns1:Bar>
        </ns1:GetResult>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The value of `Bar` has been reduced to a string, which is not accepted by the server.

After much trying I found this request works:

```
$client = new \SoapClient($url_to_wsdl);
$result = $client->GetResult([
    "Foo" => "foo_value",
    "Bar" => [
        "any" => [ "<ns1:Bar><ns1:Qux>bar_qux_value</ns1:Qux></ns1:Bar>" ]
    ]
]);
```

I have several questions:

1. Why is the Bar>Bar>Qux not in the wsdl?
2. Why are there two levels of Bar? Is that just poorly designed?
3. Why do I need the `<any>` node?
4. Is there any way I can build the request without having to inline some of the xml?

Answer (score 0):

Hello for tested in local and check your errors use [SOAP-UI](https://www.soapui.org/) create a mock of soap server from your wsdl and call that and check logs errors.

Sorry for me english.
Good luck !

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I checked out SOAP UI but I can figure out how to make a call to it. I think it can only do internal testing. The sample requests it generates don't contain what I'm looking for (the `any` nodes).